NextJS - Your deployment's build step did not complete within the maximum of 45min
I am trying to deploy a NextJS app, but I am getting this error after 45 minutes:
Your deployment's build step did not complete within the maximum of 45min
However, I can run this locally and it runs ok in the Localhost environment, but when I deploy I get the error.
Please see the screenshot for reference.


There can be many reasons why your app is taking 45 minutes to build. look at this link that has the same problem I guess: https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/4529.
Keep the Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) in your mind too. maybe that is the problem.

@AmirDanesh, I checked the link and still have the issue running.

what is the environment you are deploying to?
